# issue sent E-mail from WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic, exchange-server

I have an issue to send E-mail from my interface that developed with WebLogic. The server of WebLogic is authorized to communicate with the Exchange Server (SMTP authorized). When I send an E-mail I get this message:

[image: Sample]

Is this problem coming from the Exchange Server or the WebLogic Server.

Comment: Please post your error message as text, not as image. You can copy it from your `cmd` window.

Comment: The error message suggests you to add a mime type mapping in the web.xml for this file type (png)